# Merging tags in LXML

Tags: python, merge, lxml, tail

So: we have an XML document:

```
<items>
  <item id="1">some text</item>
  <item id="2">some <b>bold</b> text which carried onto the next line,</item>
  <item id="3"> and is <b>bold, <i>italic, <u>and underlined</u></i></b>!</item>
  <item id="4">some more boring text <i>with tags</i></item>
</items>
```

We know we want to combine the contents of items 2 and 3 so we have:

```
<item id="2_3">some <b>bold</b> ... next line,
 and is <b>bold, <i>it ... </b>!</item>
```

What's the cleanest way of handling the contents of the tags so we don't lose any nested tags / trailing text?

`list(item)` or `item.getchildren()` just give me the bold tag - i.e. not the text of the item directly.

We can play with `item[-1].tail` giving it the `text` of the second item, but this seems horrifically kludgy - there must be a better way, right?

Comment: Using ``etree.tostring(item)`` gives the text of the xml of that item but it includes itself i.e. ``<item ....> ...</item>`` close but no cigar !

Comment: you could do str =etree.tostring(item) ||
str[5:str.len() - 7] ||, though that would make it dependant on the tag.

Comment: @Rawrgulmuffins - good idea; it might be safer to greedily regex match `>(.*)<` - but it feels so **wrong**!

Comment: @DragonDave That's just because it's regex...